# linq grouping by children object property

Tags: c#, linq

I am not able to do grouping on my structure. Grouping need to be done by child property. I have `Sellers` (`List<SellerModel>`) with `Products` (`List<ProductModel>`). Each product has `Category` (`CategoryId`). As input I have `List<SellerModel>`. And as output I need Categories list. (`List<CategoryModel>`)

The model structure I need to have is as follows:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}        
    public List<SellerModel> Sellers { get; set; }            
}

public class SellerModel
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}        
    public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }            
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}        
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Guid CategoryId {get;set;} // THIS IS THE PROPERTY TO GROUP BY
}
```

Now I have to group by `ProductModel.CategoryId`.
So, the result structure is `List<CategoryModel>`, but it would not be a simple categories list. It would List that contains Sellers and Products. 
Imaging if you have list of sellers who sell different products in different categories. And now you need to know all different categories that are available. And also you have to know which seller sells which products in given category.

I was trying to do some grouping, but I am very new to LinQ and this is not basic grouping I guess. I believe I do not understand the logic how to do grouping here.

```
var t = sellers.GroupBy(x => x.Products.Select(y => y.CategoryId)).Select(a => a.Key)
```

Comment: So you want a list of all categories?

Comment: What do you want to group by what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are skipping several steps before trying to group.

The following should produce what you are looking for:

```
                // obtain a set of all { CategoryId, Seller } pairs
var n = sellers.SelectMany(s => s.Products.Select(p => new {
                    p.CategoryId, 
                    Seller = s
                }))
                // group those by CategoryId
               .GroupBy(cs => cs.CategoryId)
                // create a CategoryModel from each group
               .Select(g => new CategoryModel { 
                    Id = g.Key, 
                    Sellers = g.Select(cp => cp.Seller).ToList()
                })
                //make a list
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me and I understand your logic.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping functions work on a list and a property shared by all the elements of the list.

You have 2 choices:

- You group sellers by products and then you group this group by category based on categoryId. This way you don't lose information in the process.
- You convert your list of sellers into a bigger list of products (using SelectMany) and then you group based on categoryId.